# Dropzone sending all queue of uploaded files to the controller once

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I am trying to send multiple files in one request using DropZone js.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var file= new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
        url: any url,
        method:"post",
        paramName:"PhotoFiles",
        addRemoveLinks:true,
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });

    //Upload file onsubmit
    $('#UploadMultiFiles').submit(function(){
        file.processQueue();
    });

    file.on("sending",function(a,b,c){
        a.token=Math.random();
        c.append("token",a.token); 
    });
```

The issue is I have other inputs in the same form that is why I used `onsubmit`, and these inputs are saved in a table and the images from dropzone are saved in another table with and both tables have one to many relationship

The Controller like:

```
  public function university_offers($id){

    $data['university_offer_name']=$this->input->post('university_offer_name');
    $data['university_id_fk']=$this->input->post('university_id_fk');
    $data['university_offer_details']=$this->input->post('university_offer_details');

    if ($this->input->post('save')){

        $data2['university_offer_id_fk'] = insertrecords('university_offers',$data);
        $data2['university_id_fk'] = $data['university_id_fk'];

  //when I put the next IF at the begining of the function it works but ofcourse without the other data fields that I need.
        if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES != null){
             $data2['photo_name'] = upload_image('PhotoFiles');
             insertrecords('university_offer_photos',$data2);
    }

        if (insertrecords('university_offer_photos',$data2)==true)
            message('success','');
        redirect('Admin/university_offers/0','refresh');

    }

    $data['view']="admin/universities/university_offers";
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

What I need is sending al uploaded files and do a loop in the `controller` to save it right in the database, not sending each file to the `controller` and saving it.

**Edit:**

My view is like:

```
 <form action="university_offers/<?=$id?>" id="UploadMultiFiles" autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="m-t-5"  novalidate>
                <div class="form-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">بيانات العرض</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row p-t-20">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">إسم العرض<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="university_offer_name" class="form-control" required value="<?php if(isset($result)) echo $result['university_offer_name']?>" data-validation-required-message="يجب إدخال إسم العرض" placeholder="إسم العرض">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">إسم الجامعة<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select name="university_id_fk" id="select" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="يجب إختيار الجامعة" aria-invalid="false">
                                        <option value="">إختر الجامعة</option>
                                        <?php 
                                        foreach (selectrecords("*",'universities') as $university):
                                            $select = '';
                                            if(isset($result) && $result['university_id_fk'] == $university->university_id_pk)
                                                $select = 'selected';
                                        ?>
                                        <option <?=$select?> value="<?php echo $university->university_id_pk ?>"><?php echo $university->university_name ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">تفاصيل العرض<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea id="mymce" name="university_offer_details"><?php if(isset($result)) echo $result['university_offer_details'] ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">صور العرض<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <div class="row">
                                <?php 
                                if(isset($result)) {
                                    foreach (selectrecords('*','university_offer_photos',array('university_offer_id_fk'=>$result['university_offer_id_pk'])) as $photo):
                                        echo'
                                            <div class="form-group text-center" id="'.$photo->photo_id_pk.'">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <img style="border: none; height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 10px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="'.base_url().'public/uploads/images/'.$photo->photo_name.'">
                                                </div>
                                                <a href="#" onclick="return removePhoto('.$photo->photo_id_pk.')">حذف الملف</a>
                                            </div>
                                            ';
                                    endforeach;
                                }
                                ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropzone">
                                    <div class="dz-message">
                                        <span> Drag and Drop your files here Or Click here to upload</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <input type="hidden" id="url" value="university_offers/<?=$id?>" />
                        <?php
                        if($id == 0)
                            echo '<button type="submit" id="butt" name="save" value="save" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> حفظ</button>';
                        else
                            echo '<button type="submit" id="butt" name="edit" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> حفظ</button>';
                        ?>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> إلغاء</button>
                        <?php
                        if($id == 0)
                            echo'<button type="button" id="backword" class="btn btn-second"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> رجوع</button>';
                        else{
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="university_offer_id_pk" value="'.$result['university_offer_id_pk'].'"/>

                                <a href="'.base_url().'Admin/university_offers/0"><button type="button" class="btn btn-second"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> رجوع</button></a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

upload_image function, I put it in the Helper

```
 function upload_image($file_name){
  $CI =& get_instance();

$config['upload_path'] = 'public/uploads/images';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|Gif|ico|ICO|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|BNG|png|PNG|bmp|BMP|WMV|wmv|MP3|mp3|FLV|flv|SWF|swf';

$config['max_size']    = '1024*8';

$config['encrypt_name']=true;

  $CI->load->library('upload',$config);

if(!  $CI->upload->do_upload($file_name)){

    return  false;

}else{

    $datafile =  $CI->upload->data();

   thumb($datafile);
    watermark($datafile);
    return  $datafile['file_name'];


}}
```

Comment: [Here's how to config dropzone to upload all the files at once (it's from 2013, but looks legit).](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone) I think you're just missing `uploadMultiple : true;`

Comment: That seems to be the case

Comment: I added `uploadMultiple : true;` but what about the `controller` function .. how I put the files in the loop to add them into the database

Comment: I think you loop on the `$_FILES['PhotoFiles']` array. [Here's an example without the other submitted fields](https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/) but you'd have those apart from the $_FILES[].

Comment: You need to be more specific about your database structure and how you want to add them to a database. Do you want each image to have its own row, or will it take up one field in a row. In which case if you have multiples you have to serialize the array. I'm also not sure why you aren't using codeigniter object oriented style and instead are using helpers with plain functions not in a class.

Comment: I  want each image to have its own row, and also after changing `uploadMultiple` to `true` and I tried to `var_dump($_FILES)` the result is empty and I don't know how to do the loop to save it into the database.

Comment: Ok I see, could you post your full view as well? Ideally in a way in which it would be easy for me to drop into my IDE and have a go at it. It is weird you say that `$_FILES` is empty (you can't loop over something empty haha) but was it also empty before you changed `uploadMultiple`?

Comment: Also post the function `upload_image`... does it handle multiples or just one per iteration?

Comment: I Edit my question for what you need. Hope it helps you to fined what is the problem :). the function was doing fine when `uploadMultiple` was `false`, but after changing it to `true` to make multiple files to be transferred in one request, then the function `uploadMultiple` needed to be in `for` loop in the `controller`. How to catch `$_FILE` request to do that.

Comment: Hey Guyes .. any progress!!